# Crop images in folder - Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am trying to write a script that read all the JPG images in a folder and crop them based on this script:

```
myFolder = 'D:/Temp/';
filePattern = fullfile(myFolder, '*.jpg');
jpegFiles = dir(filePattern);

for k = 1:length(jpegFiles)
    baseFileName = jpegFiles(k).name;
    fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName); 
    %// show image   
    imshow(fullFileName)
    %// Make a binary image
    grayImage = rgb2gray(fullFileName);
    binaryImage = grayImage < 250;

    [y,x] = find(binaryImage);  %// Find row and column locations that are non-zero
    %// Find top left corner
    xmin = min(x(:));
    ymin = min(y(:));
    %// Find bottom right corner
    xmax = max(x(:));
    ymax = max(y(:));
    %// Find width and height
    width = xmax - xmin + 1;
    height = ymax - ymin + 1;
    %// Crop image
    outputImage = imcrop(fullFileName, [xmin ymin width height]);
    imshow(outputImage);
end
```

but I get this error:

```
Warning: Image is too big to fit on screen; displaying at 67% 
> In images.internal.initSize (line 71)
  In imshow (line 305)
  In Untitled2 (line 9) 
Error using rgb2gray>parse_inputs (line 82)
MAP must be a m x 3 array.

Error in rgb2gray (line 37)
X        = parse_inputs(X);

Error in Untitled2 (line 11)
grayImage = rgb2gray(fullFileName);
```

If i apply the inside of the loop on a single image it works fine.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably means that some of your images are **not** RGB but are grayscale / single channel.  You can fix this by adding in a check to see if the read in image has three channels and if it does, call `rgb2gray` accordingly.  In addition, `rgb2gray` requires an **image**, yet you are supplying a string:

```
grayImage = rgb2gray(fullFileName);
```

Use `imread` first to read in the image, then use `rgb2gray` on this image:

```
for k = 1:length(jpegFiles)
    baseFileName = jpegFiles(k).name;
    fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName); 
    %// show image   
    imshow(fullFileName)

    %// Read in image first
    img = imread(fullFileName);

    %// Make a binary image
    if size(img,3) == 3
        grayImage = rgb2gray(img);
    else
        grayImage = img;
    end

    %//....
    %//rest of your code here

end
```

Comment: I edit/update the script but it still does not work. Any more ideas?

Comment: @user2788464 I made a mistake with my code.  Please see the edit.  Forgot to change the `rgb2gray` call.